# cygwin bash find with prune option not behaving as expected

Tags: find, cygwin, subdirectory

The two commands below are yielding exactly the same file list in bash under cygwin:

```
find ../../../../.. -name "*.o" -and -path "*/common/*"
find ../../../../.. -name "*.o" -and -path "*/common/*" -prune
```

This list includes files such as:

```
../../../../../platform/abc/common/ppng.o
../../../../../platform/abc/common/variant/pxx.o
```

The list does *not* include any files without "common" in their pathnames.

What I'm trying to do is find (and ultimately eliminate) object files in all directories *but* any that have a "common" directory component. I've tried about 25 other combinations without luck.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik, -path doesn't take regular expressions. I think what you want to do is find all your object files (`.*.o`) and exclude all the common directories (`.*/common/.*`):

```
find . -regex '.*.o' -and -not -regex '.*/common/.*'
```

You can make it all case insensitive with `-iregex` if needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out -regex; that's much more flexible than what I'm used to. The example you gave works very well.